# Safer string copy function in VC++ but how to handle TCHAR*?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I was fixing all [C4996 warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4996?view=vs-2019) which is MS's proposal.
replaced sprintf with sprint_s
replaced _tcscpy with _tcscpy_s

It works without changing parameter with TCHAR[]

```
TCHAR* test; // a string argument from CLR project
TCHAR target[100];
_tcscpy(target, test); 
_tcscpy_s(target, test); // both works fine.
```

but what about TCHAR*?
I don't know how big the buffer size will be with TCHAR*

```
TCHAR* test; // a string argument from CLR project
TCHAR* target;
_tcscpy_s(target, ???, test);
```

Here are what I have looked into:

- [using strcpy_s for TCHAR pointer (Microsoft Specific)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946916/using-strcpy-s-for-tchar-pointer-microsoft-specific/2947265#2947265)
- [Microsoft _s functions, are they part of the C++ standard now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617571/microsoft-s-functions-are-they-part-of-the-c-standard-now)

But there is no solution.

Comment: `I don't know how big the buffer size will be` It will be exactly as big as you allocated it to be. `TCHAR* target;` as the code has it now is just an uninitialized pointer. You cannot copy *anything* to it before you point it to a valid allocation, and once you do that you'll know how big the buffer is that you allocated for it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer to myself with advice from @dxiv.

TCHAR* to TCHAR*

```
TCHAR* src= new TCHAR[??]; // check whether it is initialized.
TCHAR* dest= new TCHAR[??];
const int BUFFER= _tsclen(src) + 1;
_tcscpy_s(dest, BUFFER, src);
```

TCHAR[] to TCHAR*

```
TCHAR src[??] = _T("something...");
TCHAR* dest= new TCHAR[??];
const int BUFFER= _countof(src);
_tcscpy_s(dest, BUFFER, src);
```

TCHAR[] to TCHAR[]

```
TCHAR src[??] = _T("something...");
TCHAR dest[??] = _T("");
_tcscpy_s(dest, src);
```

Comment: `const int BUFFER= _tsclen(dest) + 1;` This won't work unless you first initialize the just allocated `dest` buffer with a nul-terminated string. Otherwise there is no string there to take the length of, and calling `_tsclen` will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: `const int BUFFER= _countof(dest);` Change that to `_countof(src)`. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/countof-macro?view=vs-2019) why "*_countof produces erroneous results if array is a pointer*".

Comment: @dxiv ah that was my typo. I wrote _countof(src) in my project and wrote here opposite. good correction.

Comment: and yes, in my case, there is guarantee src pointers are all initialized with a null-terminated string.